# Best option for Django Logging accross multiple processes

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing, django-logging

What is the best option for Django logging if I have info.log and error.log which are being shared across multiple processes?
One option would be Multiprocessing, another option would be SocketHandler.

Here is the link:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes